# Position: fixed not working on element and is acting glitchy. Transform is applied to siblings, but not parent element

Tags: css, position, css-position, css-transforms

To preface, I would like to acknowledge that CSS transforms affect position: fixed behavior and makes the element which is fixed become relative to the transformed element. However, this is only an issue if the *parent* is transformed, and not element siblings.

I am having trouble with an element which has 3d transformed siblings, but no transformed parent elements. I have looked extensively for any transforms on the parent element (body element), but none are found.

Here is my code:

CSS (used SASS mixins for animations)

```
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: -webkit-min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 100%;
}
body::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj4KICAgIDxmaWx0ZXIgaWQ9Im5vaXNlIiB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIj4KICAgICAgPGZlVHVyYnVsZW5jZSB0eXBlPSJmcmFjdGFsTm9pc2UiIGJhc2VGcmVxdWVuY3k9IjAuNjUiIG51bU9jdGF2ZXM9IjMiIHN0aXRjaFRpbGVzPSJzdGl0Y2giLz4KICAgICAgPGZlQmxlbmQgbW9kZT0ic2NyZWVuIi8+CiAgICA8L2ZpbHRlcj4KICAgIDxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSI1MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIiBmaWx0ZXI9InVybCgjbm9pc2UpIiBvcGFjaXR5PSIwLjUiLz4KPC9zdmc+);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.125;
}

header,
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 5vw 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.body--inactive {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #f82aff;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.name--animated {
  display: flex;
  font-family: "ArchitypograPsychodeliqu", sans-serif;
  font-display: auto;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #7b0080;
  font-size: 6.3vw;
  color: #fed4ff;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter1;
          animation-name: letter1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
          animation-delay: -0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter2;
          animation-name: letter2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
          animation-delay: -0.9s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter3;
          animation-name: letter3;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.2s;
          animation-delay: -1.2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter4;
          animation-name: letter4;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.5s;
          animation-delay: -1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter4 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter5;
          animation-name: letter5;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.8s;
          animation-delay: -1.8s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter5 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter5 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter6;
          animation-name: letter6;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.1s;
          animation-delay: -2.1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter6 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter6 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter7;
          animation-name: letter7;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.4s;
          animation-delay: -2.4s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter7 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter7 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter8;
          animation-name: letter8;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.7s;
          animation-delay: -2.7s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter8 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter8 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter9;
          animation-name: letter9;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3s;
          animation-delay: -3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter9 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter9 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter10;
          animation-name: letter10;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.3s;
          animation-delay: -3.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter10 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter10 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter11;
          animation-name: letter11;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.6s;
          animation-delay: -3.6s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter11 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter11 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter12;
          animation-name: letter12;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.9s;
          animation-delay: -3.9s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter12 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter12 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated span:nth-child(13) {
  -webkit-animation-name: letter13;
          animation-name: letter13;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
          animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.2s;
          animation-delay: -4.2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes letter13 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
@keyframes letter13 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
}
.name--animated:hover {
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #7b0080;
}

h1 {
  display: none;
}

.nav--cube {
  --width-nav-cube: 80;
  --height-nav-cube: 60;
  --depth-nav-cube: 20;
  height: calc(var(--height-nav-cube) * 1vw);
  width: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 1vw);
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(10deg);
}
.nav--cube .name--animated {
  font-size: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.073vw);
}
.nav--cube ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: "Xolonium", sans-serif;
  font-display: auto;
  width: auto;
  font-size: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.05vw);
}
.nav--cube ul::before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 3px solid #7b0080;
  border-left: 3px solid #7b0080;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7b0080;
  width: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.02vw);
  height: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.06vw);
  margin-right: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.01vw);
}
.nav--cube ul::after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 3px solid #7b0080;
  border-right: 3px solid #7b0080;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #7b0080;
  width: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.02vw);
  height: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.06vw);
  margin-left: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.01vw);
}
.nav--cube ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav--cube ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 3px;
  height: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.06vw);
  background-color: #7b0080;
  margin: 0 calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.02vw);
}
.nav--cube ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav--cube ul li a img {
  width: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.05vw);
  height: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 0.05vw);
}
.nav--cube ul #contact--link {
  color: #cd00d4;
  height: 100%;
}
.nav--cube ul #contact--link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #7b0080;
          text-decoration-color: #7b0080;
}
.nav--cube ul #contact--link:active {
  color: #f82aff;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #cd00d4;
          text-decoration-color: #cd00d4;
}
.nav--cube ul #instagram--link {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.nav--cube__side {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #c000c7;
}
.nav--cube__side:nth-of-type(1), .nav--cube__side:nth-of-type(2) {
  --coefficient-nav-cube: -0.5;
  height: calc(var(--height-nav-cube) * 1vw);
  width: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 1vw);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, calc(var(--depth-nav-cube) * 1vw * var(--coefficient-nav-cube)));
}
.nav--cube__side:nth-of-type(2) {
  --coefficient-nav-cube: 0.5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.nav--cube__side:nth-of-type(3), .nav--cube__side:nth-of-type(4) {
  --rotation-nav-cube: 90deg;
  height: calc(var(--height-nav-cube) * 1vw);
  width: calc(var(--depth-nav-cube) * 1vw);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(var(--rotation-nav-cube)) translate3d(0, 0, calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 1vw * -0.5));
}
.nav--cube__side:nth-of-type(4) {
  --rotation-nav-cube: -90deg;
}
.nav--cube__side:nth-of-type(5), .nav--cube__side:nth-of-type(6) {
  --rotation-nav-cube: -90deg;
  height: calc(var(--depth-nav-cube) * 1vw);
  width: calc(var(--width-nav-cube) * 1vw);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(var(--rotation-nav-cube)) translate3d(0, 0, calc(var(--height-nav-cube) * 1vw * -0.5));
}
.nav--cube__side:nth-of-type(6) {
  --rotation-nav-cube: 90deg;
}

.main--cube {
  --width-main-cube: 80;
  --height-main-cube: 160;
  --depth-main-cube: 40;
  height: calc(var(--height-main-cube) * 1vw);
  width: calc(var(--width-main-cube) * 1vw);
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-10deg);
}
.main--cube__side {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #c000c7;
}
.main--cube__side:nth-of-type(1), .main--cube__side:nth-of-type(2) {
  --coefficient-main-cube: -0.5;
  height: calc(var(--height-main-cube) * 1vw);
  width: calc(var(--width-main-cube) * 1vw);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, calc(var(--depth-main-cube) * 1vw * var(--coefficient-main-cube)));
}
.main--cube__side:nth-of-type(2) {
  --coefficient-main-cube: 0.5;
  padding: 20px;
}
.main--cube__side:nth-of-type(3), .main--cube__side:nth-of-type(4) {
  --rotation-main-cube: 90deg;
  height: calc(var(--height-main-cube) * 1vw);
  width: calc(var(--depth-main-cube) * 1vw);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(var(--rotation-main-cube)) translate3d(0, 0, calc(var(--width-main-cube) * 1vw * -0.5));
}
.main--cube__side:nth-of-type(4) {
  --rotation-main-cube: -90deg;
}
.main--cube__side:nth-of-type(5), .main--cube__side:nth-of-type(6) {
  --rotation-main-cube: -90deg;
  height: calc(var(--depth-main-cube) * 1vw);
  width: calc(var(--width-main-cube) * 1vw);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(var(--rotation-main-cube)) translate3d(0, 0, calc(var(--height-main-cube) * 1vw * -0.5));
}
.main--cube__side:nth-of-type(6) {
  --rotation-main-cube: 90deg;
}

.gallery {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  border: 2px solid #f82aff;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
  /* hide two middle */
}
.gallery__column {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.gallery__column--2, .gallery__column--3 {
  display: none;
}
.gallery__item {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: auto;
}
.gallery__item figcaption {
  display: none;
}
.gallery__image {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .gallery__column--2 {
    display: block;
  }
  /* show column 2 */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .gallery__column--3 {
    display: block;
  }
  /* show column 3 */
}
.contact {
  display: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #f82aff;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

form {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-display: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fed4ff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
form label {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
form textarea {
  resize: none;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
form input:not([type=submit]) {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 15vw;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
form input,
form textarea {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #f82aff;
  color: #fed4ff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
form input[type=submit],
form textarea[type=submit] {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form input[type=submit]:active,
form textarea[type=submit]:active {
  border: 2px solid #fed4ff;
}
form input:not([type=submit]):focus,
form textarea:not([type=submit]):focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 2px solid #fed4ff;
  outline: none;
}

.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.lightbox--active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
.lightbox__button {
  width: 10vw;
  margin: auto 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.lightbox__button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.lightbox__button--left {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.lightbox__button--right {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.lightbox__button--inactive {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.lightbox__button img {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.2rem #7b0080);
}
.lightbox__figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.lightbox__figure figcaption {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fed4ff;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1;
}
.lightbox__figure figcaption i {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.lightbox__image {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 85vh;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: zoom-in;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
.lightbox__image--zoom--wrapper {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.3rem #7b0080);
  border: 2px solid #c000c7;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom--active {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="nav--cube" aria-label="3D Cube with Navigation">
        <div class="nav--cube__side"></div>
        <div class="nav--cube__side" aria-label="Cube side with Navigation"></div>
        <div class="nav--cube__side"></div>
        <div class="nav--cube__side"></div>
        <div class="nav--cube__side"></div>
        <div class="nav--cube__side"></div>
    </div>
</header>
<main id="main">
    <div class="main--cube" aria-label="3D Cube with Main Content">
        <div class="main--cube__side"></div>
        <div class="main--cube__side"></div>
        <div class="main--cube__side"></div>
        <div class="main--cube__side"></div>
        <div class="main--cube__side"></div>
        <div class="main--cube__side"></div>
    </div>
</main>
<aside class="lightbox">
    <button class="lightbox__button lightbox__button--left" tabindex="0"
        aria-label="Left button to change lightbox image"
        aria-description="Press left arrow key to change lightbox image">
        <img src="assets/icons/lightbox-arrow-left.svg" alt="Left button arrow">
    </button>
    <figure class="lightbox__figure">
        <div class="lightbox__image--zoom--wrapper">
            <img alt="painting" class="lightbox__image" aria-live="assertive">
        </div>
        <figcaption class="lightbox__figure--caption" aria-live="assertive"><strong></strong>
            <i></i>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <button class="lightbox__button lightbox__button--right" aria-label="Left button to change lightbox image"
        aria-description="Press right arrow key to change lightbox image">
        <img src="assets/icons/lightbox-arrow-right.svg" alt="Right button arrow">
    </button>
</aside>
</body>

</html>
```

It gets even weirder when I was tinkering with this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/candle_wick/pen/MWXyBjB). Here, position: fixed on a sibling element to a transformed element displays some pretty weird behavior. If you remove the 'o' from the second div with class 'two', position: fixed works. It also works if you give the second div an ID.

Is this a specificity issue? I also tried changing my fixed element on my own code to include a longer class name or ID, but it broke my entire code. Position sticky doesn't work either. The only thing that fixes it is commenting out any instance of transform. My code was working earlier before I changed *something* and it started to act up so I don't know why transform on sibling elements is causing such an issue.

Comment: In the codepen, position fixed of the blue element is working fine for me. The rectangle stays put at 50px, 50px and as I scroll a bit of text shows through eventually as expected. Please could you describe more what you think is weird.

Comment: @AHaworth Interestingly, it works for me now. Earlier if I added another "o" to the end of class "two" the element would not scroll with the viewport. I wonder if it's a browser glitch?

Comment: By ‘adding another o’ do you mean the same as removing the class from the blue element?

Comment: @AHaworth What I mean is changing the class from "two" to "twoo" on the blue element, and updating the css accordingly (.two => .twoo).

Comment: Obviously this makes absolutely no difference. Is there actually any problem at all? Everything is fine in your codepen so if you still have a problem please add an example as a runnable snippet direct in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I fixed it by putting the lightbox element at the top. I'll remove some code to make things clearer for everyone.